# Белые края у текстуры OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Я загрузил текстуру 64 на 64 пикселя с параметрами:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Получилось:

[image: Текстура]

А хотелось бы так:

[image: Должно быть]

Можно ли исправить, или нужно рисовать текстуру побольще?

Comment: Похоже что у вас прозрачные пиксели имеют белый цвет. Вот интерполяция *так* и срабатывает. Следите за альфой, она важна.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо, я понял. Я прошел по массиву и поменял цвет прозрачных пикселей на черный, теперь всё в порядке.